# Server driven UI with a database in the backend

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on developing a case management system from scratch and am in the process of getting most of APIs ready. In this case the APIs are responsible for querying the PSQL database I have running on localhost via docker compose.

I started to think about the frontend aspect of the application and came across server driven UI. From what I can tell after doing some research it is predominantly for the UI aspect of the application. I started wondering how someone would try to communicate with the backend to retrieve data from the backend.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated